# React native: How do I open a completely new screen with 5 tabs after an initial questionnaire?

Tags: react-native

I do not have a code here as I may not need a code. I have a 2-question survey to start with when the app starts. Those 2 questions I have put in using 2 screens/tabs and createBottomTabNavigator.

Now when the questionnaire completes, I would like to open a completely new set of screens (consisting of let's say 5 tabs) and I do not want to show the initial 2-screens/tabs.

How do I achieve this in react native? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this by implementing a simple authentication flow.
see: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

so something like this would work:

```
function MyTabs() {
  const [questionsCompleted, setQuestionsCompleted] = React.useState(false)

  const changeQuestionsCompleted = () => {
    setQuestionsCompleted(true)
  }

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      {questionsCompleted ? (
        <>
          <Tab.Screen name="Q1" component={Q1} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Q2" component={Q2} changeQuestionsCompleted={changeQuestionsCompleted} />
        </>
      ) : (
        <Tab.Screen name="RestOfApp" component={RestOfApp} />
      )}
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```